React Navigation passing parameter through deeplink
Using my deeplink:
  FuelFinder: {
    Name: 'FuelFinder',
    Label: 'Fuel Finder',
    deeplinkPath: 'fuel-finder/:type',
  },

I would like to pass a type parameter like this:
myrac.sit://motoring/fuel-finder/diesel

In my stack I am defining the screens like this:
const motoringStack = {
  path: AppRoutes.Motoring.deeplinkPath,
  screens: {
    // Fuel finder
    [AppRoutes.FuelFinder.Name]: {
      path: AppRoutes.FuelFinder.deeplinkPath,
      screens: {
        [AppRoutes.FuelFinderSearch.Name]:
          AppRoutes.FuelFinderSearch.deeplinkPath,
      },
    },
  },
};

How can I add the type parameter and get it in my deeplink screen?
When I try and get the params they are undefined:
  const route = useRoute();

  console.log('route', route.params);

